# Divine Scrolls - Magic Effects

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, magic, divine

I can't get some doubts off my mind.

1. Do divine scrolls in D&D 5e exist? It seems that a cleric can read the scroll only when the spell is in common with an arcane class that can create it. Am I wrong?
2. Can a cleric create a Guiding Bolt scroll, for example?

Comment: I added the [tag:dnd-5e] tag, as you ask about 5e in the question. We always tag questions with the system as there are many versions of D&D and they share a lot of the names of things, but differ in their rules.

Comment: Welcome to the stack Fabio, take the [tour] when you have a moment. We require that question posts focus on one problem, so I’ve removed the paragraph about light and dark to focus your question on Clerics and spell scrolls. Feel free to create a new question post for your question about light and dark.

Comment: Is there some specific text that makes you think all scrolls are arcane or can only be created by arcane casters? The question is answerable as it is, but if there's something specific that seems to indicate there's a limitation, I'd like to see what it is.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, there are scrolls with "divine" spells, and a scroll of *guiding bolt* is possible

The **Spell Scrolls** entry on p. 200 in the *DMG* says:

> A spell scroll bears the words of a single spell, written in a mystical cipher. If the spell is on your class's spell list, you can read the scroll and cast its spell without providing any material components. Otherwise, the scroll is unintelligible.

Scrolls of spells that are only on the lists of spellcasters classified as divine can be made, there is no restriction to any specific class, neither wizards, nor arcane spell casters in general. Not in the description of spell scrolls, and also not in the intro about scrolls (p. 139) or in the crafting rules (p. 129). The only thing that is special for spell scrolls with spells from the wizard spell list is that a wizard can copy those spells into their spellbook.

As a positive proof point there is a *scroll of heroes' feast* in *Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage* (p. 76). *Heroes' feast* is a spell that does not appear on the wizard, sorcerer, warlock or bard spell lists, but only on those of divine spellcasters (druids and clerics).

Note that the concept of "divine" or "arcane" magic applies to the casters in 5e, not to the spells. The same spell, say *dispel magic* can be a divine spell if cast by a divine caster, or an arcane spell, if cast by an arcane caster. Who counts as divine or arcane is explained in the inset box **The Weave of Magic**, *PH* p. 202:

> All magic depends on the Weave, though different kinds
> of magic access it in a variety of ways. The spells of wizards,
> warlocks, sorcerers, and bards are commonly called **arcane
> magic**. [...] Eldritch knights and arcane tricksters also use arcane
> magic. The spells of clerics, druids, paladins, and rangers are
> called **divine magic**. These spellcasters’ access to the Weave
> is mediated by divine power—gods, the divine forces of
> nature, or the sacred weight of a paladin’s oath.

A cleric can craft a scroll of *guiding bolt*. Note however that the crafting rules are an optional downtime rule - if crafting is available or not is a decision for the DM.